# SQL select only 1 row in ID IN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How I can get only 1 photo for each ID in my sql request?

My gallery table:

```
+----+----------+
| id | name     |
+----+----------+
| 1  | gallery1 |
| 2  | gallery2 |
| 3  | gallery3 |
+----+----------+
```

And photos table:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |    name    | gallery_id |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | photo1.jpg |      1     |
|  2 | photo2.jpg |      1     |
|  3 | photo3.jpg |      2     |
|  4 | photo4.jpg |      3     |
|  5 | photo5.jpg |      3     |
|  6 | photo6.jpg |      3     |
+----+------------+------------+
```

I use MySQL
I selected my galleries from gallery sql then I want get one photo  for each row from photos SQL. Can you help me how I can do this ?

```
foreach($this->gallery as $val){
        $this->arr_id = $this->arr_id.$val['id'].',';
      }
      $this->arr_id = trim($this->arr_id, ',');
      echo $this->arr_id; (4,3,2,1)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want, please explain better. Do you want to select only one photo for each gallery, or something else? Show your existing SQL

Comment: Yes i want get only one photo for each gallery

Comment: If there are multiple potential candidates, then what are your criteria for deciding which one you would like in the output?

Comment: Which. One. ????

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some aggregate function and group by to filter single photo by category, as follows:

```
SELECT min(id) as photo_id FROM photos GROUP BY gallery_id
```

Now, you can make use of this information and use it to get single photo per gallery:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    photos
WHERE
    id IN (SELECT 
            MIN(id) AS photo_id
        FROM
            photos
        GROUP BY gallery_id)
```

You can use `JOIN` also instead of `WHERE IN`:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    photos
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MIN(id) AS photo_id
    FROM
        photos
    GROUP BY gallery_id) single ON (photos.id = single.photo_id)
```

If you want gallery name also, `JOIN` above with `gallery` table also:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    photos
        JOIN
    gallery ON (photos.gallery_id = gallery.id)
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MIN(id) AS photo_id
    FROM
        photos
    GROUP BY gallery_id) single ON (photos.id = single.photo_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Random photo

```
SELECT *
FROM gallery G
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT id AS photo_id, gallery_id  
        FROM photos
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
    ) p ON G.id = p.gallery_id
```

First photo :

```
SELECT *
FROM gallery G
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MIN(id) AS photo_id, gallery_id  
        FROM photos
        GROUP BY gallery_id
    ) p ON G.id = p.gallery_id
```

Last photo :

```
SELECT *
FROM gallery G
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT MAX(id) AS photo_id, gallery_id  
        FROM photos
        GROUP BY gallery_id
    ) p ON G.id = p.gallery_id
```

Comment: The first one only returns 1 photo for one gallery !?!?!

Comment: @Strawberry `LIMIT 1` isn't it ?

Comment: I think the OP wants one photo per gallery- just like your other queries.